# Sort records by a related model count, and then sort chronologically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

**Posts** have_many **upvotes**. A post can also be featured or not with the column **is_featured**.

I want to get all featured posts, ordered by upvotes (most to least), then created_at (newest to oldest).

Here is how I build up the query. #1 and #2 work, but for #3 I can't sort by dates and upvotes at the same time.

```
# 1. Get all featured posts
Posts.where(is_featured: true) 

# 2. Get all featured posts, sort by their votes in DESC order. Maybe there is an easier way?
Posts.where(is_featured: true).sort_by{|post| post.upvotes.count}.reverse! 

# 3. Get all featured posts, sort by their votes in DESC order, sort by created_at DESC (doesnt work)
Posts.where(is_featured: true).sort_by{|post| post.upvotes.count}.reverse!.sort_by{|post| post.created_at}.reverse!
```

What is the correct query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend that you implement a counter_cache for the upvotes and then simply do:

```
Posts.where(is_featured: true).order("upvotes_count DESC, created_at DESC")
```

You upvotes model should look like this

```
class Upvotes
  belong_to :posts, :counter_cache => true
  ...
end
```

Then you will need upvotes_count:integer on your posts table.

Comment: Does it sort chronologically?